# Is there a way to get the spin naturally in nonrelativistic theories?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-spin

We all know how spin is added in a rather ad-hoc way in quantum mechanics. In the other hand, in relativistic quantum field theories the spin structure arises quite naturally from the fields.

Is there not a way to construct a theory (perhaps a nonreltivistic field theory) in which the spin structure arises naturally?

Comment: Spin is an angular momentum that exists in QM.

Comment: If you apply Noether theorem without relativity you only have the usual angular momentum as a conserved quantity, if you add relativity you end up with a conserved quantity which consist in a sum of the usual angular momentum plus a term which is spin, that's why I am not sure spin would "exist" without relativity

Comment: Yes, simply by conservation of rotation. (actually it's a pretty lengthy derivation but it's found in some textbooks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Pauli equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_equation), which describe non-relativistic, spin-1/2 electrons and is the non-relativistic limit of the [Dirac equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation), can be obtained from the [Schrödinger equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation) throught minimal coupling in a rather similar way of its relativistic counterpart.

Consider the Schrödinger equation for a particle with charge $q$ in an external electrostatic potential $\Phi$:
$$ \tag{A} i \partial_t | \psi(t) \rangle = \left( \frac{\textbf{p}^2}{2m} + q \Phi \right) | \psi(t) \rangle$$
now remember from the properties of the [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Relation_to_dot_and_cross_product) the [Pauli vector identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Relation_to_dot_and_cross_product):
$$ \tag{B} (\boldsymbol \sigma \cdot \textbf a) (\boldsymbol \sigma \cdot \textbf b)
= 
\textbf a \cdot \textbf b + i \boldsymbol \sigma \cdot (\textbf a \times \textbf b),  $$
which gives in particular for $\textbf p $ the identity
$$ \tag{C} (\boldsymbol\sigma \cdot \textbf p)^2 = \textbf p \cdot \textbf p \equiv \textbf p^2, $$
which allows us to rewrite the Schrödinger equation **(A)** as
$$ \tag{C} i \partial_t | \psi(t) \rangle
= \left( \frac{(\boldsymbol \sigma \cdot \textbf p)^2}{2m} + q \Phi \right) |\psi(t)\rangle. $$
Now use the minimal coupling
$$ \tag{D} \textbf p \rightarrow \textbf p - q \textbf A, $$
obtaining from **(C)** the Pauli-Schrödinger equation:
$$ i \partial_t |\psi(t)\rangle =
\left[ \frac{1}{2m} \left( \boldsymbol \sigma \cdot (\textbf p- q \textbf A) \right)^2 + q \Phi \right] | \psi(t) \rangle $$
and squaring the expression we can explicit the interaction term between spin and magnetic field:
$$ i \partial_t |\psi(t)\rangle =
\left[ \frac{1}{2m} \left( (\text p - q \textbf A)^2 - q \boldsymbol \sigma \cdot \textbf B \right) + q \Phi\right] | \psi(t) \rangle, $$
with $ \textbf B = \nabla \times \textbf A.$